# Zero sets of power series: Analogue of Zariski?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

When we begin setting up algebraic geometry, we set up the topology to have a base of closed sets as the zero-sets of polynomials. This gives us the Zariski topology, a coarse topology for $\mathbb R$. If we build a different topology, where the closed sets are generated by the zero sets of *power series*, what's the topology we get?

The topology of power series is definitely finer than the Zariski topology; For example, $\overline{\mathbb Z} = \mathbb R$ in the Zariski topology, since only the zero polynomial vanishes at infinitely many places. On the other hand, with power series, the function $\sin(2\pi x)$ vanishes at each integer, thus $\overline{\mathbb Z} = \mathbb Z$ in the power series topology.

I guess this question boils down to characterizing the zero-sets of analytic functions since analytic functions always possess a power series. What are theorems that control this?

Comment: Under reasonable assumptions of compactness, the two topologies coincide over complex numbers and holomorphic functions.

Comment: @Mohan which two topologies? ;) There is some ambiguity.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is analytic and not identically zero, then the set
$$
Z_f=\{x{\,\mid\,}f(x)=0\}
$$
is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, at most countably infinite, and all points of $Z_f$ are isolated. See$\;$https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Real_analytic_function#Analytic_varieties_and_unique_continuation

Comment: The topology defined by holomorphic functions and the Zariski topology.

Comment: @Mohan A reasonable topology out of analytic functions should be defined locally, and the two topologies should not coincide. GAGA theorems are global.